# How many loops can be made from randomly knotting ends of threads?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, puzzle

You’re given a bag containing $n$ pieces of thread of length $l$.  $ $ You’re asked to reach down the bag and randomly pull out one end of a thread.  You’re then asked to knot this end to another end of a thread (that you also pull out randomly from the bag).  $ $  $ $ You have to do this $n$ times.

At the end of this activity, how many loops of thread will you have? 
$$ $$

---

I was given this problem some time back, but sadly, it didn’t come with a solution.
After multiple approaches, I’m fairly sure that we can’t give a *definite* answer as a function of $n$ and/or $l$ (at least, it doesn’t seem obvious). $ $   It seems the answer will be more *probabilistic* and less *combinatorial* $ $ (I may be wrong).

e.g.: the probability of making a loop on the first two picks would be $\frac{1}{2n-1}$, on the next two picks (if you did make a loop on the first two) would be $\frac{1}{2n-3}$, and so on.  $ $  $ $ I’m not sure how to develop much further from here.

Comment: if you pull a side from another thread at the beginning and you knot it with the side you already have then you have only a knot outside. My question is : in the next try, if you pull another side of a thread what should you do ?  the problem description seems a little bit ambiguous.

Comment: You put it back in the bag.  So you essentially get a *longer* thread (come to think of it).  And so the number of threads in the bag drops to $n-1$.

Comment: Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/expected-number-of-loops).

Comment: Awesome.  This does answer the question.